# grub2 loads vfat filesystem error

Tags: grub, arch-linux

after half a day of trouble shooting I still can't start Arch properly. I use a dual-boot system and Grub usually start Arch properly but often it happens that it tries to load from an unknow vfat filesystem and gives an error (vfat -> Windows partition?).
So I tried to customize the grub boot menu to add a proper boot partition.

What I have so far:

```
$ lsblk
sda
|-sda1 nfts System-reserviert
|-sda2 ntfs Windows
|-sdaX ntfs Other partitions
sdb
|-sdb1 ext4 home                /home
sdc
|-sdc1 #1MB MBR
|-sdc2 ext2 boot                /boot
|-sdc3 f2fs root                /
```

sda was partitioned with MBR and sdb and sdc with GPT. I have a BIOS computer. The installation of Archlinux was made as written in the Archlinux wiki.
Both systems were and are still bootable correctly, although I had to add Windows manually in the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file. And as said, from time to time Archlinux is not found. I want to solve that by adding a custom menu entry for Arch. But for now Grub fails to boot the new entry, complaining that I have to load the kernel first. How can I solve this?

Here is my Grub configfile (comments are removed) that was created in analogue to [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Using_labels) :

```
$ cat /etc/grub.d/40-custom
menuentry "Archlinux" {
     search --label --set-root=root "root"
     linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/disk/by-label/root rw
     initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img
}
menuentry "Windows" {
     insmod part_msdos
     insmod nfts
     insmod ntldr
     search --label --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,mados1 --hint-baremetal=ahci,msdos1 "System-reserviert"
}
```

Error: no such device: root
Error: file /boot/vmlinuz-linux not found
Error: you have to load the kernel first

Answer (score 0):

Grub is extremely picky when you try to edit it manually. And you can bork a system this way. Its probably a sneaky way but effective; Why not remove grub and its folders reinstall grub and use
 os-prober? Or you can try syslinux probably easier to edit but be precise.